# Erro 404 (Not Found) no Facebook

Tags: html, wordpress, facebook

Estou com um problema ao compartilhar links de um site no facebook pois, os links estão certos e aparece a seguinte mensagem do site ao compartilhar:

> Error 404 (Not Found)!!

O site é em wordpress e existe corretamente além de possui todas as tags `meta:og`, segue exemplo:

```
<meta property='og:locale' content='pt_BR'/>
<meta property='og:type' content='article'/>
<meta property='og:title' content='xxx'/>
<meta property='og:description' content='xxxx'/>
<meta property='og:url' content='http://xxxxxx.com.br/xxxxxx/'/>
<meta property='og:site_name' content='Titulo'/>
<meta property='article:author' content='https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxx'/>
<meta property='article:publisher' content='https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxx'/>
<meta property='fb:app_id' content='xxxxxxxxxxxxx'/>
<meta property='og:image' content='http://wwww.site.com.br/image.jpg'/>
<meta property='og:image' content='http://wwww.site.com.br/image.jpg'/>
```

Essas tags são geradas pelo plugin Yoast WordPress SEO. Alguem sabe como resolver?

Comment: Para qual link o facebook aponta? Isso normalmente acontece pela falta do protocolo `HTTP` ou `HTTPS` na URL

Comment: não entendi sua pergunta @TiagoCésarOliveira pois, o que eu faço é compartilhar minha página no facebook, no meu html tem o seguinte <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="pt-BR" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"> está correto...

Comment: Pelo que entendi, o link do Facebook retorna 404... Não é isso?

Comment: não, o facebook retorna 404 do link da minha página...

Comment: Então, seu link compartilhado lá, certo? Veja se está indo o protocolo

Comment: Veja só @TiagoCésarOliveira http://picpaste.com/facebook-WSpbfdm9.jpg

Comment: Ah, agora entendi! foi mal, pensei que fosse outra coisa

Comment: Valide a URl que você está tentando compartilhar no Facebook com o URL Linter dele. Lá ele mostrará todos os dados que captura do seu site.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que você descreveu o Facebook não está conseguindo acessar a página porque ela não está visível ao público ou não está retornando apenas para o Facebook. Caso seja a última opção, verifique se há algum código no topo da página referente ao Facebook.

Tente trocar o link do Facebook na tag html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="pt-BR" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

Por isto:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="pt-BR" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: o problema @paulo-maciel é que essa linha do html é gerada pelo próprio plugin, será que não tem alguma outra solução?

Comment: As vezes esse plugin está desatualizado, verifique se não existe outro ou tente adicionar esse recurso de comentários ao seu site de forma manual. Faz tempo que não utilizo Wordpress, então desconheço outra solução.